# While using the latest CKeditor (v.3.1), does anyone encounter a stray select box on the page where the ckeditor.js is included?

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm using the CKEditor 3.1, and find that whereever there is a  box on the page, the ckeditor causes a new empty select box to appear next to it (although it has not been applied to that specific element.)
This seems to be a known issue : http://dev.fckeditor.net/ticket/4528

Has anyone been able to get around that?
Is there any other good fckeditors you can suggest?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this i solved with some css - so the stray select box doesnt appear on the page.
if ur style is not tht flexible then i'd say avoid this editor. 
the advantage of ckeeditor - u can configure it to an extent with the settings on the config.js file for the editor.
the disadvantage - if u want an out of the box thign that integrates nicely - this is it, but unless u want to spend some time hacking into it to fix its bugs, go another way.